# Replacing ShowDialog() with Show()

Tags: c#, winforms, show, showdialog

I have a form that is being shown using ShowDialog(), thus it is a modal window.

```
private void OpenForm(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyForm testForm = new MyForm();
    ...
    testForm.Enabled = true;
    testForm.ShowDialog(this);
    var dialogOk = testForm.DialogOK;
    if(dialogOk)
    {
       //do some stuff 1
    }
}
```

There is an "OK" button on the form. When OK is clicked, DialogOk is set to true. Inside MyForm class:

```
private void OkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do some stuff 2
   ... 
   DialogOK = true;
   Hide();
}
```

I need to convert this to a non-modal window. The solution seems to be to use Show() instead of ShowDialog(), but when I use Show(), the code does not stop and wait for the OK button to be clicked, so "do some stuff 1" is never called.

Using Show(), how can I keep the behavior to have "do some stuff 1" run after the OK button is clicked?

**Update: Here is what I am trying now:**

```
public partial class MyForm: XtraForm
{
   public bool DialogOk;

   private void OkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // do some stuff 2
      ... 
      DialogOk = true;
      Close();
   }
}
```

Method 1:

```
public partial class MyMainForm : XtraForm
{
   private MyForm testForm;

   private void OpenForm(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if(testForm == null)
        {
            testForm = new MyForm();
        }
        ...
        testForm.Enabled = true;
        testForm.FormClosed += (s, a) => {
            var dialogOk = testForm.DialogOk;
            if (dialogOk)
            {
                // do some stuff 1
            }
        };
        testForm.Show(this);
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
public partial class MyMainForm : XtraForm
{
       private MyForm testForm;

       private void OpenForm(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if(testForm == null)
            {
                testForm = new MyForm();
            }
            ...
            testForm.FormClosed += testForm_Closed;
            testForm.Show(this);
        }

        private void testForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var testForm = (Form)sender;
            testForm.Closed -= testForm_Closed;

            if (testForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               // do some stuff 1
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: One way is to have the dialog form invoke a method or event within the parent form (which was passed to it as an argument) when OkClick is clicked.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you explain why you need a non-modal window to behave like a modal window? It sounds like you should keep the window modal.

Comment: Since you want to lock the execution of the main interface until the OK button is clicked on the second window, it seems to me that what you need is actually a modal window.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I need to be able to click on other windows outside of the current modal window.

Comment: BTW, `Form` have a property called `DialogResult` - set it to `DialogResult.Ok` and it will automatically hide the form and return the value - so your code changes to `if(testForm.ShowDialog(this)==DialogResult.Ok)`

Comment: @lzzydy I guess that makes sense. Then you'll have to move the code that has to run after the window closes. Either of the two answers below will work.

Comment: @lzzydy check my [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464554/5233410) using `Task` and async-await.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle `Form.Closed` event:

```
MyForm testForm = new MyForm();
testForm.Closed += testForm_Closed;
testForm.Show();

private void testForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var testForm = (Form)sender;
    testForm.Closed -= testForm_Closed;

    if (testForm.DialogResult == OK)
        // do some stuff 1
}
```

Comment: When I click OK on the form, OkClick() is still being called, but testForm_Closed is not being called. Do you think I may be missing anything?

Comment: you'll need to call Close() instead of Hide() for .Closed event to occur

Comment: @pm101 I changed Hide() to Close() but the event still isn't occurring.

Comment: Hmm, I made an example project which works fine. Can you update your code on the question to show us what you are doing new?

Comment: @pm101 I updated the code. I tried using the method in this comment and the one below. Both had the same results, where the delegate was not being called.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to move the code from `OpenForm` to the event handler `OkClick`. However, if this is not a good spot to put the code because you might want to use the same form for different tasks, you could add a handler for the `FormClosed` event, that is called after the form is closed and runs the code, e.g.:

```
private void OpenForm(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MyForm testForm = new MyForm();
    ...
    testForm.Enabled = true;
    testForm.FormClosed += (s, a) => {
      var dialogOk = testForm.DialogOK;
      if(dialogOk)
      {
         //do some stuff 1
      }
    };
    testForm.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I get the following error: "A local parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Comment: This means that there is already a parameter named `sender` on the enclosing method. I've changed to the code to use only s and a as parameter names for the delegate so that there are no conflicts anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. With this code change, the FormClosed event handler isn't being triggered when I click OK or if I close the form though. Is there anything else I may be missing here?

Comment: Instead of hiding the form, you should close it instead. Or do you want to use the same instance later again?

Comment: I don't need to use the same instance. Changing Hide() to Close() does not fix the problem either.

Comment: I just checked the code in a test project and the delegate was called after calling `Close` or using the X to close the form. So there has to be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an async event handler tied to an [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) which listens and *awaits* the close of the form

```
private asyc void OpenForm(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult>();

    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (s, args) => { 
        var  form = (MyForm)s;
        form.FormClosed -= handler;
        source.SetResult(form.DialogResult);
    }

    var testForm = new MyForm();
    testForm.FormClosed += handler; //subscribe
    //...
    testForm.Enabled = true;
    testForm.Show();

    var dialogOk = await source.Task;
    if(dialogOk == DialogResult.Ok) {
       //do some stuff 1
    }
}
```

With that you can keep the logic in the `OpenForm` and allow the code to wait without blocking.

In the form when the button is clicked then all you need to do is set the dialog result and close the form.

```
public partial class MyForm: XtraForm {

    //...

    private void OkClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // do some stuff 2
        // ... 

        DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
        Cose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, so not sure why it isn't for you (scratching head)... This form has two buttons, one which opens the same form again and another button that closes the form. The 'parent' form adds an event to the Closed event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 test = new Form1();

        test.FormClosed += Test_FormClosed;

        test.Show();
    }

    private void Test_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("closed -- do something else here!");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```